# Comparing two XBRL/XML files in R language

Tags: r, xml, xbrl, xml2

I was looking for a package in R which will allow me comparing two xml files a.xml and b.xml and  can tell me :

1) Which values are missing?
2) Which elements are missing?
3) Which attributes are missing?

And highlight these side by side.

You can take following as an example:
https://www.xbrl.org/taxonomy/int/fr/ias/ci/pfs/2002-11-15/novartis-2002-11-15.xml

I tried looking into documentation for XML2 and XML packages but these dont seem to have anything for comparison.

My basic requirement is to compare two XBRL files however since these are XMLs so comparing this way should do.

Any thoughts on this are welcome.

Comment: @bergant can you please shed some light on this please as you have done a lot of good work in XBRL?

Comment: this helped me https://github.com/bergant/XBRLFiles